# retrieve a binData record from MongoDb using C++

Tags: c++, mongodb

Could somebody please direct me to an example on how to retrieve a binData record from MongoDb using C++?
I tried this code, but returns garbage:

```
char* arrS;

while (dbResult->more())
{
    record = dbResult->next();
    strcpy(arrS, record.getField("s").binData(iLen));
}
```

"s" is my binData field.
Thank you in advance, any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Does `arrS` point to any valid memory location prior to `strcpy` operation ? I believe you know about buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `iLen` is actually a (second) return value of `binData`. You can extract the binary contents like this:

```
int iLen;
const char* p = record["s"].binData(len);
std::string content(p, iLen);
```

Answer (score -1):

.binData() returns a const char* so it should be returning a pointer to the binary data. You just need to copy that into a buffer, either explicitly allocated or a dynamic one such as a string.

eg.

```
std::string arrS;
int iLen = 0;
arrS = record.getField("s").binData(iLen);
```

I'm not sure of the iLen parameter - often this pattern is used to pass in a value of the buffer length and returns the number of bytes copied, but the [docs don't mention it](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_element.html#a8f4902eacf15f5069f4bb752bfd0aef4).

If so, you need to allocate a buffer:

```
char arrS[1000];
int iLen = sizeof(arrS);
memcpy(arrS, record.getField("s").binData(iLen));
```